# Problema al contar registros con rowCount()

Tags: php

necesito contar una cantidad de registros de una tabla que cumplan dos condiciones, el problema es que solo me esta contando un solo registro. Esta es mi funcion:

```
public function NewClients(){

        $fecha_inicio = date('Y-m-01');
        $fecha_fin = date('Y-m-t');

        $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id_nivel),date_register FROM usuarios
                                    WHERE id_nivel = 2 AND date_register
                                    BETWEEN '$fecha_inicio' AND '$fecha_fin'");
        $sql->execute();
        echo $sql->rowCount();
    }
```

Me esta imprimiendo que hay un solo registro, pero en mi tabla hay dos registros que cumplen esa condicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retorna un objeto.

```
public function NewClients($fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin){

    $fecha_inicio = date('Y-m-01');
    $fecha_fin = date('Y-m-t');

    $sql = ("SELECT COUNT(id_nivel),date_register FROM usuarios
                                WHERE id_nivel = 2 AND date_register
                                BETWEEN '$fecha_inicio' AND '$fecha_fin'");

    $sentencia = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    //$sentencia->bindParam(':fecha_inicio', $fecha_inicio);
    //$sentencia->bindParam(':fecha_fin', $fecha_fin);

    $respuesta = $sentencia->execute();
    print $sentencia->fetch("0")[0];
}
```

Comment: Ha funcionado EF43. Muchas Gracias. Pero podrias dar un detalle de la respuesta, lo unico en que tengo dudas es en el print. Porque hay que retornarlo de esa forma

Comment: En mi caso retorna esto: {"count(*)":"221","0":"221"}. un array asociativo, solamente hay que acceder directamente en la posición 0. podrías dar más detalles de tu código

Comment: La consulta si ha funcionado, me muestra correctamente los registros que cumplen esa condicion, pero lo que quiero saber es porque hay que imprimirlo de esa forma en el print.

Comment: Una pregunta @AlejoMendoza ¿necesitas saber solamente la cantidad de registros que hay, o necesitas también el valor de la columna `date_register`? EF43, ¿por qué no aplicaste al código la consulta preparada en sí, dado que la consulta es vulnerable a Inyección de código dañino?

Comment: Saludos Cedano, bueno solo queria la cantidad de registros que arrojaba la consulta. Ya lo he solucionado y tambien he preparado la consulta para evitar la inyeccion sql. Gracias